# Event dropdown doesn't work on icon in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I'm using [this method](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) for a button dropdown.

I deleted the text, and add an icon, like that :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><i class="my-icon"></i></button>
```

It works, but on Safari, the dropdown effect does not work when i click on icon.

It works around the icon, but not when I click above.

Anybody knows what to do?

Javascript code :

```
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your JavaScript code?

Comment: @Matt L. I added the javascript

Answer (score 0):

Not surely convincing but looks like safari not able to understand button type. Try to add type="button" in your html

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="dropbtn"><i class="my-icon"></i></button>
```